# jquery load function not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to load partial content after page load with using jQuery and ASP.NET MVC 4 but it is not displaying loaded content on DOM. I have searched internet but couldn't found any solution. I'm sharing what i have done.

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    var site = site || {};
    site.baseUrl = site.baseUrl || "";    
    $(document).ready(function (e) {    
        $(".partialContents").each(function (index, item) {
            var url = site.baseUrl + $(item).data("url");
            if (url && url.length > 0) {
                $.get(url, function (data) {
                    $(item).append(data);
                })                    
            }
        });        
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="partialContents" data-url="/Home/GetAds">
</div>
```

I'm loading Advertisements scripts with jQuery.

Comment: you have nested ``document.ready`` may be its issue

Comment: @EhsanSajjad how can i solve this?

Comment: remove starting ``$(function(){`` and last ``});``

Comment: @EhsanSajjad still same problem, it is loading everything else correctly but not loading elements in script tag

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? What is the value of `data` returned in the `$.get()` function?

Comment: @Usama try var url = site.baseUrl + $(item).attr("data-url");